# How can I set a css class in Html.TextBox helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to set a css class in a TextBox html helper?
This doesn't compile, obviously:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Region",Model.Region,new {class="Autocomplete"}) %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Class` is a reserved keyword, so you need to write it like this:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Region", Model.Region, new { @class="Autocomplete" }) %>
```

Comment: This is great!  I love the fact that google is indexing these pretty well now.  I found this solution within 60 seconds of asking myself "how do I set the class attribute?"

Comment: How do you add multiple classes?  e.g., <p class="someclass someotherclass">paragraph</p>.  That's html valid but when I try to add it using the new { @class="xyz abc" } neither class shows up.

Comment: @shubniggurath There must be something wrong on your side. That's the proper way to have multiple CSS-classes.

Comment: @SebNilsson - great!  Thanks.  I did two or three web searches on "multiple css classes in html.dropdownlist" etc and couldn't find a good answer.  If that's right then I'll figure out what's wrong with my code.  Thanks, thanks, thanks.